# How do you disable typing but allow copy and paste?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I am creating a webpage, and I need my users to only copy & paste into the textbox. I can't allow any typing, but only copy and paste. How would I do this, regardless of what technology I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no set way to do this.  You will have to perform a work-around like here:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/59MCu/)

I basically set the `maxlength` of the text box to 0, then when a paste event occurs, `maxlength` is changed to a high number to allow the paste, then after the paste the `maxlength` is changed back to 0 so all the user can do is delete what is in there but not type anything new.

### HTML

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" name="name" maxlength="0" />
```

### jQuery

```
$("#Text1").bind('paste', function(e) {
    $(this).attr("maxlength","1000")
});
$("#Text1").on("input",function(){
   $(this).attr("maxlength","0") 
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. Keep in mind some of the jQuery such as the use of `input` only works for most modern browsers, so it depends on your user-base if this will work 100% of the time, but you get the idea of how to implement it :)